# Build failed with an exception, while running Flutter App in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, build, build.gradle, flutter-inappwebview

Launching lib\main.dart on M2007J20CG in debug mode...

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:287:3: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Uint8List? data;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:339:3: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Uint8List data;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:6339:3: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Uint8List? body;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview.dart:206:58: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
final void Function(InAppWebViewController controller, Uint8List icon)?

```
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:1199:52: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Future postUrl({required Uri url, required Uint8List postData}) async {

```
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:1612:10: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Future<Uint8List?> takeScreenshot(

```
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:2044:10: Error: Type 'Color' not found.
Future<Color?> getMetaThemeColor() async {
^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:41:9: Error: Type 'Size' not found.

final Size initialSize;
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:184:24: Error: Type 'Size' not found.

Future setSize(Size size) async {
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:197:10: Error: Type 'Size' not found.
Future<Size?> getSize() async {
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:451:52: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
void Function(InAppWebViewController controller, Uint8List icon)?

```
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_browser/in_app_browser.dart:825:30: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
void androidOnReceivedIcon(Uint8List icon) {}
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/chrome_safari_browser/chrome_safari_browser.dart:194:3: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Uint8List icon;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh_controller.dart:77:25: Error: Type 'Color' not found.
Future setColor(Color color) async {

```
                    ^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh_controller.dart:84:35: Error: Type 'Color' not found.

Future setBackgroundColor(Color color) async {
^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/ios/in_app_webview_controller.dart:34:10: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Future<Uint8List?> createPdf(

```
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/ios/in_app_webview_controller.dart:48:10: Error: Type 'Uint8List' not found.
Future<Uint8List?> createWebArchiveData() async {
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:44:33: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'Size'.
{this.initialSize = const Size(-1, -1),
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:287:3: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
Uint8List? data;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:339:3: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
Uint8List data;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1223:36: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
(map["iosCertificates"].cast() as List)
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1223:57: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
(map["iosCertificates"].cast() as List)
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1226:63: Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
  iosCertificates!.add(X509Certificate.fromData(data: data));
  ^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1629:42: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.

  (map["iosDistinguishedNames"].cast() as List)
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1629:63: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
  (map["iosDistinguishedNames"].cast() as List)
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:1632:69: Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
  iosDistinguishedNames!.add(X509Certificate.fromData(data: data));
  ^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/types.dart:6339:3: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
  Uint8List? body;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview.dart:206:58: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
  final void Function(InAppWebViewController controller, Uint8List icon)?
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:395:11: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
  Uint8List icon =
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:396:15: Error: The getter 'Uint8List' isn't defined for the class 'InAppWebViewController'.
- 'InAppWebViewController' is from 'package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Uint8List'.

  ```
          Uint8List.fromList(call.arguments["icon"].cast<int>());
          ^^^^^^^^^
  ```

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:1199:52: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
Future postUrl({required Uri url, required Uint8List postData}) async {
^^^^^^^^^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:41:9: Error: 'Size' isn't a type.
final Size initialSize;
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:184:24: Error: 'Size' isn't a type.
Future setSize(Size size) async {
^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_webview/headless_in_app_webview.dart:451:52: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
void Function(InAppWebViewController controller, Uint8List icon)?
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/in_app_browser/in_app_browser.dart:825:30: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
void androidOnReceivedIcon(Uint8List icon) {}
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/chrome_safari_browser/chrome_safari_browser.dart:194:3: Error: 'Uint8List' isn't a type.
Uint8List icon;
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh_controller.dart:77:25: Error: 'Color' isn't a type.
Future setColor(Color color) async {
^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+3/lib/src/pull_to_refresh/pull_to_refresh_controller.dart:84:35: Error: 'Color' isn't a type.
Future setBackgroundColor(Color color) async {
^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

My Android SDK version is 33, and my API device version is 33 too.